# Sitecore performance enhancements

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms

We need our Sitecore web application to process 60-80 web requests per second. We are using Sitecore 7.0. We have tried a 1 Webserver + 1 Database server deployment, but it only processes 20-25 requests per second. Web server queues up all the other requests in the Memory. As we increase the load, memory fills up.(We did all Sitecore performance enhancements recommended). We need 4X performance to reach the goal :).

Will it be possible to achieve this goal by upgrading the existing server, or do we have to add more web servers in production environment.

Note: We are using Lucene indexing as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are some things you can consider without changing overall architecture of your deployment

**CDN to offload media and static asset requests**

This leaves your content delivery server available to handle important content queries and display logic.

Example [www.cloudflare.com](http://www.cloudflare.com)

**Configure and use Sitecore's built-in caching**

This is from the guide:

> Investigation and configuration of the Sitecore Caches is broken down
>   into multiple  tasks. This way each task is more focused and
>   simplified. The focus is on  configuration and tuning of the Sitecore
>   Database Caches (prefetch, data, and item  caches.)
>
> For configuration
>   of the output rendering caching properties, the customer should be 
>   made aware of both the Sitecore Cache Configuration Reference and the
>   Sitecore  Presentation Component Reference as to how properly enable
>   and the properties to  expire these caches.

Check out the [Sitecore Tuning Guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/64/cms_tuning_guide_sc60-64-a4.pdf)

**Find Slow Queries or Controls**

It sounds like your application follows Sitecore best practices, but I leave this note in for anyone that might find this answer.  Use Sitecore's built-in Debug mode to identify the slowest running controls and sublayouts.  Additionally, if you have Analytics set up there is a "Slow Pages" report that might give you some information on where your application is slowing down.

---

Those things being said, if you're prepared to provision additional servers and set up a load-balanced environment then read on.

1. **Separate Content Delivery and Content Management**
   To me the first logical step before load-balancing content delivery servers is to separate the content management from the equation.  This is pretty easy and the [Scaling Guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Scaling%20Guide.aspx) walks you through getting the HistoryEngine set up to keep those Lucene indexes up to date.
2. **Set up Load Balancer with 2 or more Content Delivery servers**
   Once you've done the first step this can be as easy as cloning your content delivery server and adding it to your load balancer "pool".  There are a couple of things to consider here like: Does your web application allow users to log in? So you'll need to worry about sticky sessions or machine keys.  Does your web application use file media instead of blob media? I haven't had to deal with this, but I understand that's another consideration.
3. **Scale your SQL solution**
   I've seen applications with up to four load balanced content delivery servers and the SQL Server did not have a problem - I think this will be unique to each case depending on a lot of factors: horsepower and tuning of SQL Server, content model of your application, complexity of your queries, caching configuration on content delivery servers, etc.  Again, the [Scaling Guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Scaling%20Guide.aspx) covers SQL Mirroring and Failover, so that is going to be your first stop on getting that going.

---

Finally, I would say contact Sitecore.  These guys have probably seen more of what's gone right and what's gone wrong with installations and could get you on the right path. Good luck!

Comment: Very good response, the seperation of Content Delivery og Content Management will help keep load stable, when editors are working. It probably wont deliver more performance when you are testing, but it will in a live setup.

Also get as much cached with Sitecore's cache and use other caching strategies for external data (RSS feeds, legacy data, etc.)

Also to keep things running smoothly after launch, be sure to run some index maintenace jobs on the SQL Server. The simplest is to run a rebuild once a week and really helps keep performance steady.

Answer (score 1):

**This answer written from a Sitecore developer perspective:**

Bottom line: You need to figure out exactly where your performance bottleneck is.  That is going to take some digging, but will be very worthwhile.  You should definitely be able to serve 60-80 requests/s without any trouble... but of course that makes a lot of assumptions about the nature of your site and the requests.

For my site, I found Sitecore's caching implementation to be sub-par... I created some very simple and aggressive application-specific caches in my app and this made all the difference in the world.  For instance, we have 900+ "Partner" items where our sites' advertisements live... and simply putting all these objects in an array in the Application object sped up page requests significantly.  Finding an object in a Hashtable indexed by its Item.Name or ID is going to be a lot faster than Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/itempath") or a SelectItems() call (at least, that's my experience).  If your architecture and data set will allow this strategy, we've had good experience with it.

Another thing to watch out for is XSLT renderings.  Personally, I avoid them completely in favor of ASP.NET UserControls.  The XSLT rendering is just slow.  As much as 10x slower than a native UserControl rendering the same HTML.  So if you have a few of these... replace with some custom code and you'll see a world of difference.